# Checking if a number is Humble

Tags: java, math, methods

```
static boolean isPrime(int n)
    {
        if(n<=1) return false;
        if(n==2) return true;
        if(n%2==0) return false;
        int m = (int)Math.round(Math.sqrt(n));

        for(int i=3; i <= m; i+=2)
            if(n%i==0)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    static boolean isHumble(int n)
    {   
        for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (isPrime(i) && isFactor(n, i))
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                //if(isPresent(i))
                //  return false;
                //else return true;
                return true;

            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static boolean isFactor(int val1, int val2)
    {
        return val1%val2==0;
    }

    static boolean isPresent(int n){
        for(int val : prime_factors)
            if(n==val)
                return true;
        return false;
    }

// prime_factors {2,3,5,7}
```

I am implementing an isHumble function, but for some reason something seems to be off. Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: post your error, if any. also post your *actual* output. very much helpful to us helpers.

Comment: keep telling me that 27 isn't humble, but I know it is

Comment: it would seem to me you would need to keep dividing your input number by the prime factors (as long as they divide evenly), until you can't anymore. If resulting number is 1, then your original number was humble, otherwise not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

Add 1 to your list of prime numbers, and try the following:

```
boolean isHumble(int n)
{
    if (isFactor(n)) return true;
    for(int i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
    {
        while(n%i == 0)
            if (isFactor(i))
                n /= i;
            else
                return false;
    }
    return isFactor(n);
}
```

So that those factors are removed from the number and not found later.

**Edit 2**

A simpler solution would be:

```
boolean isHumble(int n)
{
    for (int val : prime_factors)
        while (n % val == 0) n /= val;
    return (n == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's written your `isHumble` method will return false for every number because of the way your `isFactor` method is written...

Answer (score 0):

A humble number is one whose only prime factors are 2,3,5,7. That means, if you take all the "prime numbers" from 0 to n/2, only 2,3,5,7 should divide them. 
Instead you are taking all the numbers from 0 to n/2 and checking whether they are factors.

Hence in your case when i=9, the statement 
if(n%i == 0) returns to true and hence return false is getting executed.

Run your outer loop on i for only prime numbers instead of all the numbers from 0 to n/2 and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `isFactor` method could be easier be written as

```
boolean isFactor(int n){
    return prime_factors.contains(n);
}
```